# Shipping *.so and binaries while building RPM package

Tags: python, rpm, rpm-spec

I have created a python application in which I would like to ship `.so` and some binary files in the final RPM package. After long reading I found a way to add binaries/ image and other data files in `setup.py`. Now, when I build an RPM with `python setup.py bdist_rpm` command, it complains about architecture dependency:

```
    Arch dependent binaries in noarch package
error: command 'rpmbuild' failed with exit status 1
```

After googling I found that we can add:

```
#%define _binaries_in_noarch_packages_terminate_build 0
```

or removing the line `BuildArch: noarch` in the `packagename.spec` file to overcome the `rpmbuild` failure. However, every time I add or remove line from `build/bdist.linux-i686/rpm/SPECS/packagename.spec` the command `python setup.py bdist_rpm` always overwrites the `.spe` file.

Is there a way to avoid `Arch dependent binaries` and ship *.so and other binary files in rpm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The behavior of bdist_rpm is defined by a bunch of settings in:

- `/usr/lib/rpm/macros`
- `/etc/rpm/macros`
- `$HOME/.rpmmacros`

I'm willing to bet that only `/usr/lib/rpm/macros` exists on your system.  This is normal.

So, in order to prevent the "Arch dependent binaries in noarch package" error you would create `/etc/rpm/macros` or `~/.rpmmacros` and add the following:

```
%_unpackaged_files_terminate_build      0
%_binaries_in_noarch_packages_terminate_build   0
```

Do not modify `/usr/lib/rpm/macros` because that file will be overwritten by the system whenever the rpm-build package is upgraded, downgraded, or re-installed.

If you want to override the behavior for everyone on the system put the settings in `/etc/rpm/macros`.  If you want override the behavior for a particular user then add the settings to `$HOME/.rpmmacros`.

`.rpmmacros` trumps `/etc/rpm/macros` which trumps `/usr/lib/rpm/macros`.

Note: it's useful to examine `/usr/lib/rpm/macros` to see what settings are available and for syntax examples.

As a side note, `%_unpackaged_files_terminate_build      0` setting prevents the  `error: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:` error.

Comment: you can also add the following to your spec file:

%define _binaries_in_noarch_packages_terminate_build   0

Comment: I added these "%define _binaries_in_noarch_packages_terminate_build 0
%define _unpackaged_files_terminate_build      0" to spec file and it ran fine

Answer (score 7):

`.so` files are always arch dependent as far as I know.

In your case to avoid having to edit the specs-file all the time you can add `--force-arch=<your_arch>` to our `setup.py bdist_rpm`

e.g.

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm --force-arch=x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this matter in a .spec file when you try to build a new .rpm package.

Change the BuildArch from noarch to x86_64 (or whatever you have on the building system)

```
[root@devel-mga7][~/build/yate-ota]# grep Arch yate-ota.spec
BuildArch:      x86_64
[root@devel-mga7][~/build/yate-ota]#
```