# rpmbuild error: Arch dependent binaries in noarch package

Tags: rpmbuild

I'm having error to copy a dir or copy multiples files in a directory using *

```
 %install
 install -m 0755 -d $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/PBS
 install -m 0644 PBS/pbs_environment $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/PBS/pbs_environment


 mkdir -p  $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/PBS/bin
 cp -r PBS/bin/* $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/PBS/bin


 %files
 /PBS
```

I would get this error for the cp -r PBS/bin/* :

Requires(rpmlib): rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1 rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
Requires: /bin/sh libX11.so.6()(64bit) libXft.so.2()(64bit) libc.so.6()(64bit) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.10)(64bit) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.6)(64bit) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.9)(64bit) libcrypt.so.1()(64bit) libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) libdl.so.2()(64bit) libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) libedit.so.0()(64bit) libfontconfig.so.1()(64bit) libfreetype.so.6()(64bit) libm.so.6()(64bit) libncurses.so.6()(64bit) libpthread.so.0()(64bit) libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) libpython3.6m.so.1.0()(64bit) libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) libtcl8.6.so()(64bit) libtinfo.so.6()(64bit) libtk8.6.so()(64bit) libutil.so.1()(64bit) libz.so.1()(64bit) rtld(GNU_HASH)
error: Arch dependent binaries in noarch package

I'm a complete noob in regard to rpmbuild. Any tips would be appreciated.
Thanks very much

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288374/shipping-so-and-binaries-while-building-rpm-package to me